# How to use refs to shift focus to an P element?

Tags: reactjs

I have a timeline component when you click on a month that shifts focus to reports of that month

I have used refs to try and achieve this. I update the state on click of an element on the timeline so I use the focus function in `componentDidUpdate` method

```
data.map(factsheet => {
  const heading = factsheet && toShortFormat(factsheet.month).slice(3);
  return (
    <Cell extraClasses="factsheets-container">
      <p className="month-name" ref={heading}>{heading}</p>
      <Cell extraClasses="factsheets">
        {this.factsheetsList(factsheet.factsheets)}
      </Cell>
    </Cell>
  )
});
```

This snippet is for refs in `onclick` function

```
const ref = `${month}-${year}`;
this.setState({
  ref: this.refs[ref],
})
```

This is the `componentDidUpdate` function

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  const { ref } = this.state
  ref && ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref).focus();
}
```

The focus doesn't shift

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are using the `ref` because we can't see your whole Component, but, from what I see, there is something wrong (for example, you should have one `refObject` for each `Cell`, and you should not save the refs in the state).
I can't even see where the `onClick` function is fired :)

Anyways, here's a fiddle that may help you:

```js
const data = [
    {title: "Foo"},
    {title: "Bar"},
    {title: "Miz"}
];

class App extends React.Component {
    inputListRef;
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.inputListRef = Array.from({ length: props.data.length}, () => React.createRef());
    }
    
    handleClick = (e) => {
        const dataIndex = e.target.getAttribute("data-index");
        this.inputListRef[dataIndex].current.focus()
        console.log();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Your Data</h1>
                {this.props.data.map((el, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="data-cell">
                            <button data-index={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me for Focus</button>
                            <input type="text" ref={this.inputListRef[index]} value={el.title}></input>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.data-cell {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.data-cell + .data-cell {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

I've used the `input` element so you can see the focus easily. As you can see, I create an array of refs, and I save each `input` element in one different entry of the array.

Notice I've used the `data-index` custom attribute: you could also write `onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}` and change the `handleClick()` to expect a number parameter; I wrote like I wrote because I wanted to avoid arrow function in `render()` method.

Does it help you?